# How to create chat server using openssl in c

Tags: c, sockets, ssl, networking, encryption

I want to create a encrypted chat server using openssl in C so, have taken the code from :http://simplestcodings.blogspot.in/2010/08/secure-server-client-using-openssl-in-c.html

I want to convert this code to concurrent chat server but how can i do that?

when i try to connect client with server it's just showing :

on server side:

```
Connection: 127.0.0.1:34902
No certificates.
Client msg: "Hello???"
```

on client side :

```
Connected with AES256-GCM-SHA384 encryption
Server certificates:
Subject: /C=IN/ST=UK/L=DDN/O=UPES/OU=IT/CN=KAVIN/emailAddress=kavin_sharma@yahoo.com
Issuer: /C=IN/ST=UK/L=DDN/O=UPES/OU=IT/CN=KAVIN/emailAddress=kavin_sharma@yahoo.com
Received: "<html><body><pre>Hello???</pre></body></html>

"
```

---

I want to do a encrypted chat between client and server ?

server.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <resolv.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>

#define FAIL    -1

int OpenConnection(const char *hostname, int port)
{   int sd;
    struct hostent *host;
    struct sockaddr_in addr;

    if ( (host = gethostbyname(hostname)) == NULL )
    {
        perror(hostname);
        abort();
    }
    sd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    bzero(&addr, sizeof(addr));
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(port);
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = *(long*)(host->h_addr);
    if ( connect(sd, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr)) != 0 )
    {
        close(sd);
        perror(hostname);
        abort();
    }
    return sd;
}

SSL_CTX* InitCTX(void)
{   SSL_METHOD *method;
    SSL_CTX *ctx;

    OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();  /* Load cryptos, et.al. */
    SSL_load_error_strings();   /* Bring in and register error messages */
    method = TLSv1_2_client_method();  /* Create new client-method instance */
    ctx = SSL_CTX_new(method);   /* Create new context */
    if ( ctx == NULL )
    {
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        abort();
    }
    return ctx;
}

void ShowCerts(SSL* ssl)
{   X509 *cert;
    char *line;

    cert = SSL_get_peer_certificate(ssl); /* get the server's certificate */
    if ( cert != NULL )
    {
        printf("Server certificates:\n");
        line = X509_NAME_oneline(X509_get_subject_name(cert), 0, 0);
        printf("Subject: %s\n", line);
        free(line);       /* free the malloc'ed string */
        line = X509_NAME_oneline(X509_get_issuer_name(cert), 0, 0);
        printf("Issuer: %s\n", line);
        free(line);       /* free the malloc'ed string */
        X509_free(cert);     /* free the malloc'ed certificate copy */
    }
    else
        printf("Info: No client certificates configured.\n");
}

int main(int count, char *strings[])
{   SSL_CTX *ctx;
    int server;
    SSL *ssl;
    char buf[1024];
    int bytes;
    char *hostname, *portnum;

    if ( count != 3 )
    {
        printf("usage: %s <hostname> <portnum>\n", strings[0]);
        exit(0);
    }
    SSL_library_init();
    hostname=strings[1];
    portnum=strings[2];

    ctx = InitCTX();
    server = OpenConnection(hostname, atoi(portnum));
    ssl = SSL_new(ctx);      /* create new SSL connection state */
    SSL_set_fd(ssl, server);    /* attach the socket descriptor */
    if ( SSL_connect(ssl) == FAIL )   /* perform the connection */
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
    else

    {   char *msg = "Hello???";

        printf("Connected with %s encryption\n", SSL_get_cipher(ssl));
        ShowCerts(ssl);
        /* get any certs */
    while(1){
        SSL_write(ssl, msg, strlen(msg));   /* encrypt & send message */
        bytes = SSL_read(ssl, buf, sizeof(buf)); /* get reply & decrypt */
        buf[bytes] = 0;
        printf("Received: \"%s\"\n", buf);
        SSL_free(ssl);        /* release connection state */

}
   close(server);         /* close socket */
    SSL_CTX_free(ctx);        /* release context */

   return 0;
}
```

Client.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <resolv.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>

#define FAIL    -1

int OpenConnection(const char *hostname, int port)
{   int sd;
    struct hostent *host;
    struct sockaddr_in addr;

    if ( (host = gethostbyname(hostname)) == NULL )
    {
        perror(hostname);
        abort();
    }
    sd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    bzero(&addr, sizeof(addr));
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(port);
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = *(long*)(host->h_addr);
    if ( connect(sd, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr)) != 0 )
    {
        close(sd);
        perror(hostname);
        abort();
    }
    return sd;
}

SSL_CTX* InitCTX(void)
{   SSL_METHOD *method;
    SSL_CTX *ctx;

    OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();  /* Load cryptos, et.al. */
    SSL_load_error_strings();   /* Bring in and register error messages */
    method = TLSv1_2_client_method();  /* Create new client-method instance */
    ctx = SSL_CTX_new(method);   /* Create new context */
    if ( ctx == NULL )
    {
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        abort();
    }
    return ctx;
}

void ShowCerts(SSL* ssl)
{   X509 *cert;
    char *line;

    cert = SSL_get_peer_certificate(ssl); /* get the server's certificate */
    if ( cert != NULL )
    {
        printf("Server certificates:\n");
        line = X509_NAME_oneline(X509_get_subject_name(cert), 0, 0);
        printf("Subject: %s\n", line);
        free(line);       /* free the malloc'ed string */
        line = X509_NAME_oneline(X509_get_issuer_name(cert), 0, 0);
        printf("Issuer: %s\n", line);
        free(line);       /* free the malloc'ed string */
        X509_free(cert);     /* free the malloc'ed certificate copy */
    }
    else
        printf("Info: No client certificates configured.\n");
}

int main(int count, char *strings[])
{   SSL_CTX *ctx;
    int server;
    SSL *ssl;
    char buf[1024];
    int bytes;
    char *hostname, *portnum;

    if ( count != 3 )
    {
        printf("usage: %s <hostname> <portnum>\n", strings[0]);
        exit(0);
    }
    SSL_library_init();
    hostname=strings[1];
    portnum=strings[2];

    ctx = InitCTX();
    server = OpenConnection(hostname, atoi(portnum));
    ssl = SSL_new(ctx);      /* create new SSL connection state */
    SSL_set_fd(ssl, server);    /* attach the socket descriptor */
    if ( SSL_connect(ssl) == FAIL )   /* perform the connection */
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
    else

    {   char *msg = "Hello???";

        printf("Connected with %s encryption\n", SSL_get_cipher(ssl));
        ShowCerts(ssl);
        /* get any certs */
    while(1){
        SSL_write(ssl, msg, strlen(msg));   /* encrypt & send message */
        bytes = SSL_read(ssl, buf, sizeof(buf)); /* get reply & decrypt */
        buf[bytes] = 0;
        printf("Received: \"%s\"\n", buf);
        SSL_free(ssl);        /* release connection state */

}
   close(server);         /* close socket */
    SSL_CTX_free(ctx);        /* release context */

   return 0;
}
```

Please Comment the changes in the code for converting this code to encrypted chat server

Answer (score 3):

As you are already using SSL functionality, your chat program is actually secured. But from your post, it looks like you want to enhance your secure connection. 
For implementing encryption and decryption you can try,

//Encryption

```
AES_KEY encKey;
AES_set_encrypt_key(key, 128, &encKey);
AES_encrypt(text, out, &encKey);
```

//Decryption

```
AES_KEY decKey;
AES_set_decrypt_key(key,128,&decKey);
AES_decrypt(out, text, &decKey);
```

Note : `key` should be common

Comment: Actually i want to send and receive messages between cilent and server so that it will work like a encrypted chating  app Because in above code i m unable to send and receive messages it's just saying ("hello")

Comment: The logic is to encrypt "hello" message and then send the encrypted message. Now at other side with the use of common key, decrypt the message. If any fraud/man in middle attacks comes in then encrypted message will be delivered. It will be impossible to decrypt the message without common key. These are the functions for encryption and decryption. You can use it in your code.

Comment: This begs the question: How will the keys be shared between the two devices and how will the device/person be authenticated.

Comment: Keys are shared during installation/configuration process. This key will be a private key so it need to be protected. For authenticating server and client, there is a concept called `certificate pinning`. You can search for it.

Comment: How we can convert this code to full duplex chat server means both side communication between client server

Comment: "Keys are shared during installation/configuration process." is vague and just hand waving, it is a large problem.

Comment: When any certificate is created then its respective public key will also be created. This public key is needed to verify the certificate. So in order to authenticate server or client, Public key should be present at other end so that it should validate the incoming cert and proceed with further connection. In this way, you can achieve mutual authentication also. Any fraud server/client connection can be avoided.

Comment: @kavin, As per my logic for creating full duplex chat program, you will need to create basically 2 threads for each client. one for accepting new message from client and second thread for sending reply to it. Please share if you face any difficulty

Comment: sir can you make changes to this code so that it will convert into full duplex chat program